# How does ExpandableListView works in Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, expandablelistview

i have a custom expandableListView with 2 groups . When i expand the first group everything is fine; but when i expand the second group it shows again the content from the first group. How can i fix this ??

```
public class MiCuentaActivity extends Fragment {


    Usuario user;

     ExpandableListAdapter listAdapter;
        ExpandableListView expListView;
        List<String> listDataHeader;
        HashMap<String, List<HistorialOferta>> listDataChild;
        HashMap<String, List<HistorialOferta>> listWonSubastas;


     public MiCuentaActivity(Usuario user) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
         this.user=user;
    }

     public MiCuentaActivity(){

     }

    @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_mi_cuenta, container, false);

            //StrictMode.enableDefaults();

            expListView= (ExpandableListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.listaExpan);

            expListView.setOnGroupExpandListener(new OnGroupExpandListener() {

                @Override
                public void onGroupExpand(int arg0) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), arg0+" expandeed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });

            new TareaSync().execute(new ApiConnector("cuenta", this.user));

            return rootView;
        }




    private class TareaSync extends AsyncTask<ApiConnector, Void, HashMap<String, List<HistorialOferta>>>{

        @Override
        protected HashMap<String, List<HistorialOferta>> doInBackground(ApiConnector... params) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            listDataHeader=new ArrayList<String>();
            listDataChild=new HashMap<String, List<HistorialOferta>>();

            //ApiConnector api=new ApiConnector("cuenta", this.user);
            List<HistorialOferta> ofertas=params[0].getCuenta();
            List<HistorialOferta> lstWon=params[0].getWon();

            listDataHeader.add("Historial Ofertas");
            listDataHeader.add("Subastas Ganadas");



            listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(0), ofertas);
            listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(1), lstWon);

            return listDataChild;

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute( HashMap<String, List<HistorialOferta>> list) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            setListAdapter(list);
        }

        private void setListAdapter( HashMap<String, List<HistorialOferta>> list) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            expListView.setAdapter(new ExpandableList(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), listDataHeader, list));
        }




    }
}
```

Adapter:

```
@Override
public Object getChild(int arg0, int arg1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return this.listOfertas.get(this._listDataHeader.get(arg0)).get(arg1);
}


@Override
    public View getChildView(int groupId, int childId, boolean arg2,
            View convertView, ViewGroup arg4) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        HistorialOferta ho = (HistorialOferta) getChild(groupId, childId);

        TableLayout table;

        if (convertView == null) {

            if(groupId==0){

            LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = infalInflater
                    .inflate(R.layout.list_expand_item, null);

            table = (TableLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.maintable);

            }

            if(groupId==1){

                LayoutInflater infla=(LayoutInflater) this._context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

                convertView=infla.inflate(R.layout.list_expand_won_item, null);

                table=(TableLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.maintableWon);

            }



}


return convertView;




        }
```

Comment: Do you really think it has something to do with a fragment? Why? Did you try same code in an activity?

Comment: Yes i tried the same with activity and everything works fine

Answer (score 0):

[This might help you out.](http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html#ViewHolder)

Also, know that in `ListView`s, views are recycled later, so you need to make sure you actually reset everything. Using the `ViewHolder` pattern should help. Google that term to find more examples.

You could also have it that your `HistorialOferta` objects hold the two layout values that you need, so instead of using the `if(groupId==0)` code, you could say something like:

```
convertView = infalInflater.inflate(ho.getViewId(), null)
table = (TableLayout) convertView.findViewById(ho.getTableViewID());
```

Also, you never actually do anything with your `convertView` aside from inflating the view; is this what you intended?

Comment: I already debbuged the getChildView method and the problems is here:   HistorialOferta ho = (HistorialOferta) getChild(**groupId**, childId);   Here **groupId says 0 instead of 1** when i expand the second group; that is why in the second group i see the same data from the first group